# Firebase: How to retrieve value from database then modify it and generate a new document with that value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the `postId` value of the last document created. I retrieved it but I could not find a way to bring that value out of the query. The problem with my code is that the variable that I am querying is trapped inside the promise and I am stuck on finding how to extract it.

```
exports.postOnePost = (req, res) => {
  const first = db
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then(function (documentSnapshots) {
      const lastPostId = documentSnapshots.docs[
        documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1
      ].get("postId");
      console.log(lastPostId); // logs 10257
    });
```

I wanted to take `lastPostId`  and increment it by one when a new post is added. When I added `console.log(lastVisible)` outside the function, it is not defined.

```
  const newPost = {
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    postId: lastPostId++, // This does not work
    body: req.body.body,
  };

  db.collection("posts")
    .add(newPost)
    .then((doc) => {
      const resPost = newPost;
      resPost.docId = doc.id;
      res.json(resPost);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

My database documents look like this:

```
{
      body: { stringValue: 'this is my body', valueType: 'stringValue' },
      createdAt: {
        stringValue: '2020-09-28T15:48:42.903Z',
        valueType: 'stringValue'
      },
      postId: { integerValue: '10257', valueType: 'integerValue' },
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what's wrong with the code you've already written.  Since we can't see your database, we don't know if your query actually matches any documents, so you might want to show that as well.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to have incrementing post IDs like this? Each of your post documents already has a unique random ID assigned by `add()`.  If this field doesn't have a specific purpose, you're better off not trying to compute it, as it requires extra reads to compute.  What you have now also has the problem of a race condition if two clients try to add a new post at the same time.

Comment: I wanted this functionality because the posts have this number in their title and this number is related to the administrative part. There are at most 30 to 40 posts a day. Would the worst case scenario be that both newly added documents have the same ID or does the function crash?

Comment: Can this "administrative part" use the random ID already assigned to the document instead?  That would be a lot easier.

Comment: The random ID would be too long and hard to search by the user.

Comment: Then assign a shorter random ID.

Comment: @BillCheng instead of searching this long id. You can work out with title or description something like that with [algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) and firebase combination

Comment: I agree with what Doug said that you might consider using the id generated by Firestore, but if you really need it to work this way, what you will have to do is make a read to get the document with the latest `createdAt` while assemblying your `newPost`, you can do that by querying and ordering the collection by `createdAt` and then limit the results to 1. Let me know if this work or if you need an example.

Comment: @RafaelLemos I have queried and ordered the data in the first block of code but I could not find a way to assemble it in the ```newPost```

Comment: I did not saw that, sorry, but from what I understood these 2 blocks of javascript code are all part of the same function, correct? If so, why don't you just add the second block to the `then()` of your first query? That would make it work since you would only run the remainder of the code right after the `lastPostId` variable is set.

Comment: @RafaelLemos It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.createPost = (req, res) => {
  db.collection("posts")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then(function (documentSnapshots) {
      let lastDocId = documentSnapshots.docs[
        documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1
      ].get("postId");

      if (req.body.body.trim() === "") {
        return res.status(400).json({ body: "Body must not be empty" });
      }

      lastDocId++;

      const newPost = {
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        postId: lastDocId,
        body: req.body.body,
      };

      db.collection("posts")
        .add(newPost)
        .then((doc) => {
          const resPost = newPost;
          resPost.docId = doc.id;
          res.json(resPost);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
          console.error(err);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```